# How to print a name from a list c#

Tags: c#

So I'm working on a library management system and I'm new to C# so you may see me here a lot, the issue I'm currently having revolves around this. I'm trying to make it search in my list for the author and it succeeds in doing that, I just don't know how to make it print out the result to make it appear on the console as it currently just prints "Author  exists!".

```
public static void LetaEfterBok()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter an author to search for a book: ");
            string search = Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (Bok b in newBok)
            {
                Bok Bok = new Bok();
                if (b.namn.Equals(search))
                    Console.Write("Author " + Bok.Författare + " exists!");
            }

        }
```

If needed, here is the lists and variables

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Bibliotek
{
    //Definerar klassen Bok
    class Bok
    {
        public string ID
        { get; set; }
        public int tempID;
        public string Författare
        { get; set; }
        public string namn
        { get; set; }
        public int BokCount;
        public int x;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static List<Bok> newBok = new List<Bok>();
        static List<BorrowDetails> borrowList = new List<BorrowDetails>();
        static Bok Bok = new Bok();
        static BorrowDetails borrow = new BorrowDetails();

        //Menyn och startsidan till programmet
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader("bokfil.txt");
            string s;
            while((s = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Bok Bok = new Bok();
                string[] BokData = s.Split(',');
                Bok.namn = BokData[0];
                Bok.Författare = BokData[1];
                Bok.ID = BokData[2];
                Bok.tempID = int.Parse(Bok.ID);
                newBok.Add(Bok);
            }
            readFile.Close();
```

Comment: `+ b.Författare +` ??

Comment: Have you tried `Console.Write("Author " + b.Författare + " exists!");`? `Bok bok = new Bok();` is unnecessary - `b` already refers to the current `Bok` in the loop

Comment: Thanks, should have realized that. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

try if this method works for you...

```
            public void LetaEfterBok()
            {
                Console.Write("Enter an author to search for a book: ");
                string search = Console.ReadLine();
                var book = newBok.FirstOrDefault(b => { return b.namn.Equals(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); } );
                if(book != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Author " + book.Författare + " exists!");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the OOP thing and give your class `Bok` some functionality to display information about itself. You should override the `ToString()` method such that anytime you do `WriteLine(b)` where `b` is a `Bok` it would print a string with information of the book.

For example:

```
//Definerar klassen Bok
class Bok
{
    public string ID
    { get; set; }
    public int tempID;
    public string Författare
    { get; set; }
    public string namn
    { get; set; }
    public int BokCount;
    public int x;

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return $"Title:{Författare}, Author:{namn}, ID:{ID} ({BokCount} Count)";
    }
}
```

which can be used in the search as

```
public static void LetaEfterBok()
{
    Console.Write("Enter an author to search for a book: ");
    string search = Console.ReadLine();
    foreach (Bok b in newBok)
    {
        if (b.namn.Equals(search))
        {
            Console.Write($"{b} Exists!");
        }
    }
}
```

To add more flexibility, also add a function in the `Bok` class that tries to match the author, and use the `List<T>.Find()` method to search the list

```
//Definerar klassen Bok
public class Bok 
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int tempID;
    public string Författare { get; set; } 
    public string namn { get; set; }
    public int BokCount;
    public int x;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Author:{Författare}, Name:{namn}, ID:{ID} ({BokCount} Count)";
    }

    public bool MatchAuthor(string name) => namn.ToUpper().StartsWith(name.ToUpper());
}

    public static void LetaEfterBok()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter an author to search for a book: ");
        string search = Console.ReadLine();
        Bok match = newBok.Find((b) => b.MatchAuthor(search));
        if (match!=null)
        {
            Console.Write($"{b} Exists!");
        }
    }
```